# jquery .fadein .fadeout callback nesting not ordering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to nest fadein and fadeout methods in order to get the following effect. I would like the characters in 10 seperate tags to one by one fadeout, change text and then fade in. With what I know about callback functions the following code should achieve that but the effect I am getting now is all the elements change simultaneously and the text change does not wait for the fadeout resulting in the text flashing and then fading out and in. What am I doing wrong!! Here is a simplified version of what I have currently.

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
echo '<div onclick="addname(this)">';
for ($i=0; i<10; i++){
    echo '<h1 id="temp'.$i.'">Y</h1>';
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
function addname(item){
    //Other stuff that works fine
    hideChar(0);
}
function hideChar(i){
    if(i<10){
        var tag = "temp" + i;
        var x = document.getElementById(tag);
        $(x).fadeOut(200, showChar(i));
    }
}
function showChar(i){
    var tag = "temp" + i;
    var x = document.getElementById(tag);
    var j = i+1;
    $(x).html("X");
    $(x).fadeIn(200, hideChar(j));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing your function as the callback properly. When you include the `()` - the function will be triggered immediately - omit the `()` to pass it along:

```
$(x).fadeOut(200, showChar);
```

The default parameters will be passed along. If you need something other than the default - you'll have to use an anonymous function to call yours:

```
$(x).fadeOut(200, function() {
    showChar(i)
});
```

Comment: how do i pass a parameter for the function

Comment: And the anonymous function DOES wait? Thanks!